# Is it possible to send udp packet via a v6 socket to a v4 dst?

Tags: udp

when I use linux's "sendto(....)" to send some udp packet, I got "invalid argument" error from system.
After some check, I found that I try to send a udp packet via a v6 socekt to a ipv4 destination
, I'm not sure whether it is the reason why "invalid argument" comes from system, so want to raise my question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a `PF_INET6` socket can send to IPv4 destination addresses with `sendto()` - as long as you haven't bound it to an IPv6 local address, anyway.